# python 2.7 using twill submit error

Tags: python, twill

My python code to submit a value to Google:

```
from twill.commands import *
go('www.google.com')
showforms()
formclear('1')
fv("1", "q", "python")
showforms()
submit('btnG')
```

When it is run it shows the following error:

```
***MissingSchema: Invalid URL u'/search': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///search?***
```

Answer (score 1):

The key is `formaction('1', 'www.google.com/search')`, So in your case:

```
from twill.commands import *
go('www.google.com')
showforms()
formclear('1')
fv("1", "q", "python")
formaction('1', 'www.google.com/search')
showforms()
submit('btnG')
```

As for getting the code to actually search, I'm not sure.

You can do a google search by url with `"http://www.google.com/?q=" + searchFor"`